# Change the extra field data in Many-to-many relationship in Django

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have a Many-to-many relationship with additional fields and I want to be able to change data in these fields (e.g. the status of friendship). How can I do that? All the info I found is about how to just read these data.

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    # other fields
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True, through='Friendship',
                                    through_fields=('user', 'friend'),
                                    symmetrical=False,
                                    related_name='user_friends')

class Friendship(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='friendships1')
    friend = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='friendships2')
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['user', 'friend']]
```

I tried this and that didn't work, though no error was shown:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
watched_user = User.objects.get(id=watched_user_id)
Friendship.objects.filter(user=user.profile, friend=watched_user.profile).status = 5
user.save()
```

I can't call Friendship.save() as it has no self.

And also I tried this and again no effect and no error:

```
user.profile.friends.set([watched_user.profile], through_defaults={'status': 5})
user.save()
```

And this gives me an error that there's no friend field and shows me the fields of Profile, not Friendship:

```
user.profile.user_friends.get(user=user.profile, friend=watched_user.profile).status=5
```

Please help me!

Upd: the answer helped and it works now! Thanks!
Though I still wonder if this is the only way or it can also be done from the user.profile side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with:

```
friendship = Friendship.objects.get(
    user=user.profile,
    friend=watched_user.profile
)
friendship.status = 5
friendship.save()
```

Here however there can be *multiple* `Friendship`s between the same two users.

We can update all these friendships in bulk with:

```
Friendship.objects.filter(
    user=user.profile,
    friend=watched_user.profile
).update(status=5)
```